# How can I use '{}' to redirect the output of a command run through find's -exec option?

Tags: linux, find, redirection

I am trying to automate an `svnadmin dump` command for a backup script, and I want to do something like this:

```
find /var/svn/* \( ! -name dir -prune \) -type d -exec svnadmin dump {} > {}.svn \;
```

This seems to work, in that it looks through each svn repository in `/var/svn`, and runs `svnadmin dump` on it.

However, the second `{}` in the exec command doesn't get substituted for the name of the directory being processed.  It basically just results a single file named `{}.svn`.

I suspect that this is because the shell interprets `>` to end the `find` command, and it tries redirecting stdout from that command to the file named `{}.svn`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do the redirection like this:

```
find /var/svn/* \( ! -name dir -prune \) -type d -exec sh -c 'svnadmin dump {} > {}.svn' \;
```

and the correct substitution will be done.

Comment: This is flawed and bad practice. Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1327980/432690). The right way is to pass `{}` as an argument to `sh` and then (inside `sh`) refer to it as `"$0"` or `"$1"` or so.

Answer (score 5):

No, however you can write a simple bash script to do that then call it from find.
Example (**/tmp/dump.sh**):

```
#!/bin/sh
svn admin dump "$1" > "$1".svn
```

then:

```
find /var/svn/* \( ! -name dir -prune \) -type d -exec sh /tmp/dump.sh '{}' \;
```