# Appending new lines to multiple files

Tags: command-line, unix, find, sh

I'm trying to append new lines to multiple files with the following command:

```
find -name *.ovpn -exec sh echo "line to append" >> {} \;
```

before doing this, I ran a different command to make sure it would work the way I expected:

```
find -name *.ovpn -exec sh echo "hello" \;
```

but all this does is print out "sh: 0: Can't open echo" for every file found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are few issues.

`>>` in your first command will be interpreted by your current shell as a redirection to a file literally named `{}`, unless it's quoted.

`*.ovpn` may be expanded by shell globbing before `find` ever runs. This will happen if you have at least one object in the current directory that matches the pattern. You do want to quote this. Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).

You get `Can't open echo` because indeed you're telling `sh` to open `echo`. To execute a command you need `sh -c`.

`find` without specifying the path is not portable (compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1322369/432690)). While you may get away with this, I mention the issue to make the answer more useful for other users.

This is the improved version of your first command that *kinda* works (don't run it, keep reading):

```
find . -name '*.ovpn' -exec sh -c 'echo "line to append" >> "{}"' \;
```

Notice I had to double quote `{}` inside single quotes. These double quotes are "seen" by the `sh` and make filenames with spaces etc. work as redirection targets. Without quotes you may end up with like `echo "line to append" >> foo bar.ovpn` which is equivalent to `echo "line to append" bar.ovpn >> foo`. Quoting makes it `echo "line to append" >> "foo bar.ovpn"` instead.

Unfortunately filenames containing `"` will break this syntax.

The right way to pass `{}` to `sh` is not to include it in the command string but to pass its content as a separate argument:

```
find . -name '*.ovpn' -exec sh -c 'echo "line to append" >> "$0"' {} \;
```

`$0` inside the command string expands to the first argument our `sh` gets after `-c '…'`. Now even `"` in filename won't break the syntax.

Usually (like in a script) to refer to the first argument you use `$1`. This is the reason some users would rather use a dummy argument to be `$0`, like this:

```
find . -name '*.ovpn' -exec sh -c 'echo "line to append" >> "$1"' dummy {} \;
```

If it was a script, `$0` would expand to its name. That's why it's not uncommon to see this `dummy` actually being `sh` (or `bash`, if one calls `bash -c …` etc.; check [this link](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)). Like this:

```
find . -name '*.ovpn' -exec sh -c 'echo "line to append" >> "$1"' sh {} \;
```

But wait! `find` calls a separate `sh` for every single file. I don't expect you to have thousands `.ovpn` files, but in general you might want to process many files without spawning unnecessary processes. We can optimize the approach with `tee -a` that can write to multiple files as a single process:

```
find . -name '*.ovpn' -exec sh -c 'echo "line to append" | tee -a "$@" >/dev/null' sh {} +
```

Notice `{} +`, this passes multiple paths at once. Inside the command executed by `sh -c` we retrieve them with `"$@"`, which expands to `"$1" "$2" "$3" …`. In this case a dummy argument that populates (unused) `$0` is a must.

In general there is also this issue: [*Why is `printf` better than `echo`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) However in this case you're using `echo` without options and the string it gets is static, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

My script to save multiline into a `.csv` file:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
    sleep 1s
    str="\""$(date)"\""
    echo   ${str} >>333.csv
    
    # begin add next row
    echo ",\"" >>333.csv
    # append multiline result
    ps >>333.csv
    # end add next row
    echo "\"" >>333.csv
    
    # begin add next row
    echo ",\"" >>333.csv
    # append multiline result
    df -h >>333.csv
    # end add next row
    echo "\"" >>333.csv
    
    sed -i ":a;N;s/\"\n\,/\"\,/g;ta" ./333.csv
done
```

Comment: Why did you give same answer to different questions?