# find and grep produce different output if executed from script file or command line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, grep

I'm using these commands to to search in multiple pdfs, given a file path:

`>>find /home/ad0x/Documents/Skola/Flervariabel/Tentor -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "phrase"' \;`

Where `phrase` is the term you want to search for in the pdfs. This works as expected. I get all the occurrences of the word "volym".
[image: Output in terminal]

When I try to do the same thing in a .sh script (search.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter term to search for: " phrase
find /home/ad0x/Documents/Skola/Flervariabel/Tentor -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$phrase"' \;
echo "Search completed"
```

---

```
 >>./search.sh
 >>Enter term to search for:volym
```

It outputs every line in every pdf.
The output:
[image: outputs every line in every pdf]

I suspect it has something to with how `read` interprets the input, but I haven't found a solution to my problem online.

Comment: Changed it to single quotes, and now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct culprit is `$phrase` in single quotes. This is not the only issue.

#### What happens

This is the relevant code (note I use ellipsis `…` for the least interesting part; such line is meant to be understood by humans, not directly executed in a shell):

```
find … -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$phrase"' \;
```

The shell that interprets the script holds the value of the `phrase` variable; let's say the value is `volym`. In the above command everything that is in single quotes is left untouched because this is how single quoting works; so `$phrase` is not expanded yet. The shell only parses `\` which informs it the following `;` is not meant to separate commands, it should be treated as a command line argument for `find`.

When the `find` utility is run, this is what it sees as arguments (starting from 0th i.e. the `find` itself; one argument per line, except `…` which denotes multiple less interesting arguments):

```
find
…
-exec
sh
-c
pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$phrase"
;
```

Note the last but one line is one long argument.

Let's suppose `foo.pdf` is found and `-exec` is going to do its job. All arguments between `-exec` and `;` become a new command after `{}` gets substituted by `foo.pdf`. The new command will be (again, starting from 0th argument; one argument per line):

```
sh
-c
pdftotext "foo.pdf" - | grep --with-filename --label="foo.pdf" --color "$phrase"
```

So `sh` runs, it gets `-c` and therefore knows the next argument should be run as if it was typed in the command line:

```
pdftotext "foo.pdf" - | grep --with-filename --label="foo.pdf" --color "$phrase"
```

This is the moment `$phrase` is expanded. It expands to nothing (the last word becomes `""`) because it hasn't been set in this shell. It would expand to `volym` if you exported the variable in your script; but you didn't. I wouldn't export though; in my opinion in this case exporting would unnecessarily pollute the environment.

#### Solution? Not yet

Putting `$phrase` outside of single quotes *seems* like a good idea. It will work in some cases. The most naive approach:

```
find … -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "'$phrase'"' \;
```

It's flawed. With the phrase being `" ; -exec rm "{}` these are arguments our `find` will see:

```
find
…
-exec
sh
-c
pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color ""
;
-exec
rm
"{}"
;
```

Your PDFs are gone. Artificial example? Maybe. Even if you're the only one using the script, such code injection vulnerability is nothing good.

This was because `$phrase` wasn't quoted at all. You probably know you should almost always put variables in double quotes. Let's do this. An improved approach:

```
find … -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "'"$phrase"'"' \;
```

With the phrase being `" ; -exec rm "{}` this `find` will see:

```
find
…
-exec
sh
-c
pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "" ; -exec rm "{}"
;
```

Looks somewhat better; still flawed though, because for `foo.pdf` `sh` will try to run:

```
pdftotext "foo.pdf" - | grep --with-filename --label="foo.pdf" --color "" ; -exec rm "foo.pdf"
```

The last part will most likely throw an error because there is no `-exec` command. What if the phrase was `" ; rm "{}`? What if it was `" ; rm -rf ~/"`.

There is more. Let the phrase be `volym` (quite safe) but name one of your PDFs `"; rm -rf ~ #.pdf` (this is possible in few filesystems, including ext family). After `{}`-s are substituted `sh` will run something like this:

```
pdftotext "/home/ad0x/…/"; rm -rf ~ #.pdf" - | grep …
```

I guess`pdftotext` will fail (irrelevant); then your files are gone; then `#` starts a comment, whatever.

#### Solution

This is the right way to pass your `{}` and `$phrase` to `sh` *safely*:

```
find … -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "$1" - | grep --with-filename --label="$1" --color "$2"' dummy {} "$phrase" \;
```

When this `sh` executes the given command string, `$1` gets expanded to whatever `find` substituted for `{}`, `$2` gets expanded to whatever the original shell substituted for `$phrase`. In the context of `sh` these parameters are properly quoted, so you can no more inject code. ([This other answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1327980/432690) explains `dummy`).

Even now there's room for improvement. What if the phrase was `-f`? The `grep` part would eventually be:

```
grep --with-filename --label="…" --color "-f"
```

it would complain about the missing argument. Use `--` to indicate end of options; `-f` after `--` won't be treated as an option. The same applies to `pdftotext` (although in your particular case every path to PDF must begin with `/home` so it cannot be interpreted as an option; but in general `$1` may expand to a string that looks like an option). Our `sh` invocation is already immune because `sh` takes options before a command string and our command string cannot be mistaken for an option (still `sh -c -- 'pdftotext …' …` will do no harm). More robust command:

```
find … -exec sh -c 'pdftotext -- "$1" - | grep --with-filename --label="$1" --color -- "$2"' dummy {} "$phrase" \;
```