# How to remove extension from pathname passed as {} in `find -exec`?

Tags: unix, find, file-extension, string-manipulation

Given the situation that audio needs to be extracted from video files residing in subdirectories, how would one go about properly naming the resulting files?

The following one-liner works, but retains the old file extension.

```sh
find -name "*.mp4" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -vn -acodec copy {}.aac -hide_banner \;
```

Current outcome:

```
foobar.mp4 --> foobar.mp4.aac
```

Desired outcome:

```
foobar.mp4 --> foobar.aac
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no mechanism in `find` itself that allows you to get a substring from whatever is substituted for `{}`. Even adding a suffix (like you did: `{}.aac`) may not be supported. [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> A *utility_name* or argument containing only the two characters "{}" shall be replaced by the current pathname. If a *utility_name* or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether *find* replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.

With many implementations things like `foo{}bar` do work though, nevertheless be warned. To do something more you definitely need a tool that will manipulate the string; usually a shell. In your case:

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -acodec copy "${1%.*}.aac" -hide_banner' sh {} \;
```

Here `${1%.*}` is responsible for getting the pathname without extension.

You may be tempted to replace `ffmpeg -i "$1"` with `ffmpeg -i "{}"` inside the command string passed to `sh`. Don't do this. [My other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1327980/432690) explains why the latter is wrong (and why `find . -name …` is better than `find -name …`).

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks also for linking to your other answer -- it clearly explains some questions I had about this solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: amazing, thank you. I used this for renaming `gunzip` files to append an extension

Answer (score 0):

Using the `fd` command (a `find` alternative), this could be solved with:

```sh
fd -e mp4 -x ffmpeg -i {} -vn -acodec copy {.}.aac -hide_banner
```

where:

- `fd` *invoke fd command*
- `-e mp4` *search for files with the mp4 extension*
- `-x` *exec command for each search result*
- `ffmpeg -i {}`*placeholder {} contains the current search result passed to ffmpeg as input*
- `{.}` *output path without file extension (note the dot)*

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be :

```
for file in $(find . -name "*mp4")
do
ffmpeg -i $file -vn -acodec copy [other parameters if required] ${file%%.mp4}.aac
done
```

**EDIT:**
I have no idea why I might have thought of such a loop, when the simpler one suffices:

```
for file in *.mp4
do
ffmpeg -i $file -vn -acodec copy [other parameters if required] ${file%.mp4}.aac
done
```

However if a recursive `find` is really required, based on the comment by Scott I decided to improve the last answer. I use a while loop with input from find through process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
ffmpeg -nostdin -i $file -vn -acodec copy [other parameters if required] ${file%.mp4}.aac
done< <(find . -name "*.mp4")
```

Note that ffmpeg requires `-nostdin` in a while loop. exec and xargs in general may be more efficient than while loops, but since this instance would have ffmpeg do the processing, I don't feel there is a significant performance hit.

Comment: (1) [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/23408)  (2) `"*mp4"` ≠ `"*.mp4"`  (3) [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408).  (4) Using the double `%` in `${file%%.mp4}` is unnecessary and confusing.  (5) General reference: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/23408)